# No transactions/positions to Chart Quantstrat, "logical" error?

Tags: r, quantstrat

I get the error message that the are no transactions/positions to chart despite the use of signals and rules.
Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong?
Is it maybe in the logical development of rules?
I want my rules to do what follows:
Enter long AND exit short if CNOwma crosses above 0.6.
Enter short AND exit long if CNOwma crosses below 0.6.
Please refer to the following code.
The error is in the last line.

Thank you.

```
library(devtools)
library(quantmod)
library(quantstrat)
library(TTR)
library(IKTrading)

rm(list = ls(.blotter), envir = .blotter)
initdate <- "2010-01-01"
from <- "2012-01-01" #start of backtest
to <- "2017-31-12" #end of backtest

Sys.setenv(TZ= "EST") #Set up environment for timestamps

currency("USD") #Set up environment for currency to be used

symbols <- c("RUT") #symbols used in our backtest
getSymbols("^RUT",src="yahoo", from="2012-01-01", to="2017-12-31", periodicity="daily")

stock(symbols, currency = "USD", multiplier = 1) #tells quanstrat what instruments present and what currency to use

n <- 30

wma <-  WMA(Cl(RUT), n=4, wts=c(1:4))
wmamaxt <-  rollmaxr(wma, n, fill = NA)
wmamint <- - rollmaxr(- wma, n, fill = NA)
CNOwma <- function (RUT) {(wma - wmamint) / (wmamaxt - wmamint)}

tradesize <-10000 #default trade size
initeq <- 100000 #default initial equity in our portfolio

strategy.st <- portfolio.st <- account.st <- "firststrat" #naming strategy, portfolio and account

#removes old portfolio and strategy from environment
rm.strat(portfolio.st)
rm.strat(strategy.st) 

#initialize portfolio, account, orders and strategy objects
initPortf(portfolio.st, symbols = symbols, initDate = initdate, currency = "USD")

initAcct(account.st, portfolios = portfolio.st, initDate = initdate, currency = "USD", initEq = initeq)

initOrders(portfolio.st, initDate = initdate)
strategy(strategy.st, store=TRUE)

add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st,
name = 'CNOwma',
arguments = list(x = quote(Cl(mktdata)), n=4),
label = 'CNOwma4')
add.signal(strategy.st, name = "sigThreshold",
arguments = list(column = "CNOwma4", threshold = 0.6,
relationship = "gt", cross = TRUE),
label = "longthreshold")


add.signal(strategy.st, name = "sigThreshold",
arguments = list(column = "CNOwma4", threshold = 0.6,
relationship = "lt", cross = TRUE),
label = "shortthreshold")




add.rule(strategy.st, name = "ruleSignal",
arguments = list(sigcol = "longthreshold", sigval = TRUE,
orderqty = "all", ordertype = "market",
orderside = "long", replace = FALSE,
prefer = "Open"), osFUN = IKTrading::osMaxDollar,
tradeSize = tradesize, maxSize = tradesize, type = "enter")


add.rule(strategy.st, name = "ruleSignal",
arguments = list(sigcol = "shortthreshold", sigval = TRUE,
orderqty = "all", ordertype = "market",
orderside = "long", replace = FALSE,
prefer = "Open"),
type = "exit")

add.rule(strategy.st, name = "ruleSignal",
arguments = list(sigcol = "shortthreshold", sigval = TRUE,
orderqty = "all", ordertype = "market",
orderside = "short", replace = FALSE,
prefer = "Open"),osFUN = IKTrading::osMaxDollar, 
tradeSize = tradesize, maxSize = tradesize, type = "enter")

add.rule(strategy.st, name = "ruleSignal",
arguments = list(sigcol = "longthreshold", sigval = TRUE,
orderqty = "all", ordertype = "market",
orderside = "short", replace = FALSE,
prefer = "Open"),
type = "exit")



out <- applyStrategy(strategy = strategy.st, portfolios = portfolio.st)
updatePortf(portfolio.st)
daterange <- time(getPortfolio(portfolio.st)$summary)[-1]

updateAcct(account.st, daterange)
updateEndEq(account.st)


for(symbol in symbols){

chart.Posn(Portfolio = portfolio.st, Symbol = symbol, 
TA= c("add_SMA(n=50, col='blue')", "add_SMA(n=200, col='red')"))
}

Error in chart.Posn(Portfolio = portfolio.st, Symbol = symbol, TA = c("add_SMA(n=50, col='blue')",  : 
  no transactions/positions to chart
```

Comment: You really should read about [**minimal**, verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You have pasted *a lot* of code, say that there's an error *somewhere in there*, and effectively ask us to install a dozen or so non-CRAN packages just to find out where things break. I suggest you can probably make a much smaller reproducible toy problem that demonstrates everything you need, and not require a scrolling code window.

Comment: The error is just in the last line. You need all the code to get there as the last line should chart the results obtained in the previous coding.

Comment: There is a lot of code in there that I *know* just looking at it that you don't need (e.g., multiple calls to `install_github` for the same package; `rm(...)`; `from` and `to` are never referenced once assigned; you load but do not use `png`.) Good luck, Pietro, you're asking for a lot to go through all of that, and we don't even have the literal text of the error (or is the subject of the question all of the error text?).

Comment: The subject is the error text. But thank you for the suggestion, I will delete the question and make a new, more specific one.

Comment: No need to delete it, you can edit it in-place and save yourself some effort.

Comment: The thing is that I am really new in R and programming and it is difficult for me to make a selection of the relevant parts that can cause the problem...

Comment: Being new to programming is not the problem, and learning how to ask questions like this *well* is a studied trait. It's unlikely to be natural to most. Is `portfolio.st` (or whatever it is pointing to) a large object? (I confess to *despising* how the quant tools force you to work in side-effect in the global environment. Horribly difficult to work-around some of their crutches, troubleshooting -- as we can see here -- is often much harder than it needs to be. What ever happened to *functional programming*??)

Comment: I do not know the range for which an object can be called large but I do not think it can be considered large. It contains just a strategy with a couple of signals and four rules.

Comment: If there is a way you can pass us *just* `portfolio.st` (with no other variable) where we can try your last line of code and get the error, that is the way to go. We don't need the entire journey if we can be started immediately before the problem area.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not think there is a way. I would need to give you the add.indicator function, the add.signal and the add.rules and the function for the indicator as well. I guess that the whole code is needed.

Comment: Sorry, I just went through the code and because of my familiarity, I don't see where things are falling short. `out` is `NULL`, which seems odd. `portfolio.st` is just a string, so that's no help to me. Sorry, I'm not experienced enough with `quantmod` (messed-up) way of doing things to be able to troubleshoot this, sorry.

Comment: Thank you anyway r2evans. I solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue.

A lot of errors arising with backtesting in Quantstrat are due to misspecification of column names.

The problem was solved by changing the code to:

```
add.signal(strategy.st, name = "sigThreshold",
arguments = list(column = "X1.CNOwma4", threshold = 0.6,
relationship = "gt", cross = TRUE),
label = "longthreshold")

add.signal(strategy.st, name = "sigThreshold",
arguments = list(column = "X1.CNOwma4", threshold = 0.6,
relationship = "lt", cross = TRUE),
label = "shortthreshold")
```

That is, column = "CNOwma4" was substituted by column = "X1.CNOwma4"